# centering a text vertically in button which has image

Tags: html, css

I have css and html like below.Here the text and image is not in same line.I want both to be in same line and centered vertically.

```css
.online:before {
  content: url(http://www.dreamaion.com/img_icons/on.png);
}
.butt {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0d92d9;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 22px 0px 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="online butt">Download</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following settings to the *before pseudo element*:

```
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
```

```css
.online::before {
  content: url(http://www.dreamaion.com/img_icons/on.png);
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
.butt {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #0d92d9;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 13px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 22px 0px 22px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="online butt">Download</div>
<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two way. Please add any one style to the `.online::before`. I prefer the first one.

```
vertical-align: middle; 
display: inline-block;
```

Or

```
 vertical-align: -30%;
```